# Centos 7 updated kernel to kernel-3.10.0-862 using YUM

Tags: centos, kernel, yum

I need to upgrade my centos OS to `kernel-3.10.0-862` to address the security issue.  When I run   `yum check-update|grep kernel` Gives only 693.21

```
kernel.x86_64                      3.10.0-693.21.1.el7          updates
```

I do see the updated kernel here :
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

What is the correct method to install these update using yum command?

Thanks
SR

Update:

```
# rpm -qa kernel\*
kernel-3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64

# yum list installed | grep kernel
kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-693.11.1.el7             @updates
kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-693.11.6.el7             @updates
kernel-headers.x86_64                 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7             @updates
kernel-tools.x86_64                   3.10.0-693.11.6.el7             @updates
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64              3.10.0-693.11.6.el7             @updates
```

**yum file for updates**

```
#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: Well I am not sure but I think `sudo yum update` command updates it.

Comment: No, it not showing the new kernel. trying to find out the right process, how others are updating the kernel.

Comment: @sfgroups Which kernel do you have installed? That link shows version 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.

Comment: @sfgroups Post the output of `rpm -qa kernel\*` and/or `yum list installed | grep kernel`.

Comment: Check content of your centos repo file in /var/yum.repos.d/. The most probably you have specified some mirror which wasn't updated yet.

Comment: The `3.10.0-862` kernel will most likely be available in CentOS 7.5, which I have not seen released yet.  Did you check if patches for your security issues were back ported to CentOS 7.4?

Comment: @NasirRiley, updated the post with yum and rpm command output

Comment: @JaroslavKucera, I have added yum.repos.d dir content file for patch update. its pointing to centos mirror.

Comment: @GracefulRestart  Is there a place check this patch is back ported to 7.4

Comment: You could always look at [the source](https://git.centos.org/log/rpms!kernel/c7).  Since you have the kernel installed, you could get a quick summary from `rpm -q --changelog kernel-$(uname -r) | less`.  Looking at the CentOS kernel source, they did an import from `kernel-3.10.0-862.el7` recently which may contain the patches you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `/etc/yum.repos.d`, you should see a repo called `CentOS-CR.repo` which will be disabled. Set `enabled` to `1` and then `yum list available | grep kernel` and you'll see the kernel packages for `3.10.0-862`.

After that, you can `yum update` or `yum install kernel*` to get the new kernel packages.

I just ran `yum update` on my Centos 7.4 text box and everything seems to be working okay with the usual tasks after `3.10.0-862` was installed.

Comment: Thanks we can use this command to enable CR repo. `yum-config-manager --enable cr`

Answer (score 0):

1. Update kernel level:
   https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/
2. Run this

   ```
   yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml-devel
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure that installing kernel *headers* is the way forward for this question. Neither is adding a 3rd-party repository when the OP sees the updated package in the repo.